# Feedme Pagination by Token

Tags: plugin-feedme

Has anyone used a pagination token when paginating Feedme? I currently use Firestore and they don't use a full pagination URL but a token you append onto your next URL.

Initial URL
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA`

Pagination URL
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA?pageToken=Ab7e2991jej91od727`

In the Response

```
"nextPageToken": "AFTOeJwxKBJYSXXPpKyhOmB4_-SifKCDzUH0mhJchn1u5hknl3iutUKaPez8OVyR99PZM2014ZU1EpZt4GnUHwHBnwM0P1B9Z-yDhTyqTrmsVt4SIffOXCyxq1Yl7iZQJ0c1ltGHpuV9KWgUH6mvl6rHdCA"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the one who posted that bug report regarding cursor pagination.  I just wanted to share a simple version of the code I'm using in case it's useful for anyone. I'm using Airtable so you can see I'm only running the function if the feed source is an Airtable URL.

For reference, I'm getting an offset value like `abcdefg` from the API and I'm changing it to `https://my-api-url.com/feed1/abcdefg` to get the next page of results.

You can run this from a module like the one you can generate at https://pluginfactory.io/

```
use craft\feedme\events\FeedDataEvent;
use craft\feedme\services\DataTypes;
use yii\base\Event;


class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
      Craft::setAlias('@modules', __DIR__);
      if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()) {
          $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\console\\controllers';
      } else {
          $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\controllers';
      }

      parent::init();

      /* Changes the Airtable API pagination key on the fly */

      Event::on(DataTypes::class, DataTypes::EVENT_AFTER_FETCH_FEED, function(FeedDataEvent $event) {
        $response = $event->response;
        $feedUrl = $event->url;
        
        /* Only run if this is an Airtable feed with a response */
        if ( strpos($feedUrl, "airtable") && isset($response['data']) ) : 
          $data = json_decode($response['data']);
          
          /* We only need to update the event if there's an offset key */
          if ( isset($data->offset) ) {

            /* Break the URL up into it's components */
            $url = parse_url($feedUrl);
            $baseUrl = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . $url['path'];
            parse_str($url['query'], $params);

            /* Update the current query with the new offset value */
            $params['offset'] = $data->offset;

            /* Rebuild the pagination URL */
            $data->offset = $baseUrl . '?' . http_build_query($params, $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);

            /* Return the data to the event */
            $response['data'] = json_encode($data);
            $event->response = $response;
          }
        endif;
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I just want to say how much I appreciate this! It's saved me hours of time.

Comment: @dmatthams - Awesome, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

First, you'll want to make sure you're on the latest FeedMe release as a bug around this was recently fixed: https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/694

You might also need a plugin that hooks into the `EVENT_AFTER_FETCH_FEED` event to do some offset transformation based on the tokens passed in.